# Retrieving FB data with fbgraph in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am currently writing a little app in node.js that uses the fbgraph npm module. I'm retrieving the latest post from a specific page and I want to get the message and the ID from that post. This data will be passed into variables for later use.

Currently I can get the post using the below:

```
graph.setAccessToken("TOKEN");

var graphObject = graph
    .get("/791011260991925?fields=posts.limit(1){id,message}", function(err, res) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
    });
```

The data returned as displayed on the graph api explorer is this:

```
{
  "posts": {
    "data": [{
        "id": "791011260991925_990809784345404",
        "message": "Message content is here"
     }]
  },
  "id": "791011260991925"
}
```

I'm unsure how to extract the id and the message from inside the data object and assign these into variables? I have tried using

```
var post_id = res.posts.data(id);
```

But this will just return undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. A friend at work managed to work it out.

The data returned is actually in an array so to extrapolate the data out you need to do the following...

```
var firstPost = res.posts.data[0];

var id = firstPost.id;
var message = firstPost.message;
```

Cheers